# How to make VS Code IntelliSense work with `.mm` file extentions?

Tags: c++, vscode-extensions, objective-c++

When I change the file extension from `.cpp` to `.mm` IntelliSense and `Go to definition` stops working. How can I set it up to with `.mm` files as well?

Comment: why do you use `.mm` for cpp files?

Comment: I need to merge objective C and C++ so need to compile it with objective-c++ compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is association of `.mm` files with C++, you merely need to add this association in `.vscode/settings.json` file of your project:

```json
{
    ...
    "files.associations": {
        "*.mm": "cpp",
        ...
    },
}
```

Be advised that VSCode is actually able to differentiate Objective-C and Objective-C++ languages. And if you alter the default association, VSCode will drop (possible) support for the language. (however to my knowledge there is no a viable language-server extension for Objective-C/Objective-C++)